# Single balanced mixer, multi-tone analysis

Tags: rf, filter, microwave, mixer, non-linear

I realized the circuit shown below on ADS.

[image: single balanced diode mixer]

Schematic of the mixer can be shown below.

[image: SBM on ADS]

As can be clearly seen from the figure below, to perform a multi-tone analysis RF signal is feeded with two tones having equal amplitudes. Also, if you compare the figures of the schematics, there are additional low-pass and high-pass filters on the mixer.

Components of the low pass filter is calculated by using AADE Filter Design software, filter which is a Butterworth LPF is shown below.
[image: LPF]
The problem arises when the two tone harmonic balance simulation gives the results which can be shown below.
[image: results of the mixer]

I feed input with two equal amplitudes, but at the output I get two non-equal amplitudes. Marker 2 and marker 4 should be equal.

Why do I get such a "distorted" output?

Comment: You're feeding your output signal via a low pass filter and this will attenuate higher frequencies. Maybe enough for this difference to be seen.

Comment: But the pass-band of the low pass filter is 0Hz-500MHz. Why would filter attenuate a signal at the 200MHz? The reason why I put a LPF is to keep IF port clean from RF and LO signals. RF_freq=3.8GHz, LO_freq=3.6GHz; together they create 200MHz. @Andyaka

Comment: Don't argue. Instead, check out what I say and remove this uncertainty.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said, can you elaborate more? @Andyaka

Comment: You haven't provided enough information in your question for anyone reading it to have no-doubt that the low pass filter isn't a potential culprit.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for feedback. @Andyaka

Comment: No, It's not as simple as that - you have not demonstrated to me that the filter isn't having an effect and only you have the simulation set-up to check that out. For me to tell that your filter isn't a potential problem I would have to simulate it and, of course, I can't do that - only you can. But, it's not easy because of the effect of the diodes feeding it and those extra inductors. I can't actually be sure that all of that isn't causing your problem.

Comment: It is not because of the filter, after the tests I conducted I can clearly state that filter is not guilty. Instead of filter, I directly connected the diodes to IF port. It gives the same error. Furthermore, if I connect RF and LO short at the end of the diodes it also gives the same error. Therefore, filter is "clean". I have been stuck at this problem for a long time, at least two months, what is the source of this problem? @Andyaka

Comment: Well, if you can convert your "main circuit" into something that has electrical components (as per your added pi filter) it might be easier to analyse by more people. But, what you have just said is totally relevant to your question. The problem for me is not seeing a proper full schematic using proper symbols. I just do not get along with your main picture.

Comment: Check the resolution of the FFT, and make sure you're avoiding any transients (i.e. only the steady-state). If the software has behavioural sources, you could also try performing an FFT on the signal with behavioural arithmetic, i.e. pure math (no nonlinearities,  RLC, or coupled inductors). That should give you an ideal response that you can use as a guide.